# Rotating an OCX control in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm using the PaperPort OCX to view .MAX files in Delphi 7.  The problem is, about half of the images have the wrong orientation, and the OCX has no built in means of rotating the image, only zooming in on it.

Is there any way to rotate the control entirely, or is there another control I can use to view .MAX files that allows image rotation?

Comment: You're 100% sure the PaperPort OCX doesn't contain an API to rotate the image? Seems like something they should have included.  Did you examine the TLB file yourself?

Comment: @David: it is probably larger than a .min file. I guess it is this: http://filext.com/file-extension/MAX .

Comment: @Warren P: The OCX was included as-is by ScanSoft/Nuance.  It was originally used for their PaperPort viewer, which also doesn't allow rotation.  COM inspector showed nothing useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only answer the first of your questions. There is no way to rotate the control itself. If the control doesn't allow rotating the image, you will have to find another control.

Comment: This is what I feared.  It's incredibly difficult to track down an image control that supports .MAX.  First, every weekend dev who ever made an image control calls it "image control max 2600" and second, Google and Bing, despite my best efforts to filter them out, always assume I'm really looking for 3D Studio stuff.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to look for an alternative too, and I know what you mean. Frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know for sure, but maybe the control supports the [IViewObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680763%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface. If so, you can use it to paint it yourself using its [Draw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688655%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method. Of course you would have to know somehow whether to paint it rotated or not and it would be only for display, not for interaction. But maybe this is all you need.

Comment: You could also try to capture the part of the screen that shows the image and display the result in a standard bitmap viewer.